# Авторизация через одноклассники

Tags: php, oauth, odnoklassniki-api

Помогите найти скрипт php, авторизации через API одноклассники. Никак найти не могу...

Заранее благодарен за помощь!

Answer (score 2):

[Смотрите, знакомтесь](http://dev.odnoklassniki.ru/wiki/display/ok/The+OAuth+2.0+Protocol)

И вот ещё что есть:

```
<?php
$user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; ru; rv:1.9.2.13) ' .
           'Gecko/20101203 Firefox/3.6.13 ( .NET CLR 3.5.30729)';

$login = 'логин'; 
$password = 'пароль';
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $user_agent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, dirname(__FILE__) . '/cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, dirname(__FILE__) . '/cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.odnoklassniki.ru/dk?cmd=AnonymLogin&amp;st.cmd=anonymLogin&amp;tkn=941');

$post = array(
           'st.redirect' => '',
           'st.posted' => 'set',
           'st.email' => $login,
           'st.password' => $password,
           'st.screenSize' => '',
           'st.browserSize' => '',
                       'st.flashVer' => ''
       );

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($post));
$answer = curl_exec($ch);

// в ответ получили главную страницу
echo $answer;

curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Сейчас указанная ссылка не работает. Актуальная, скорее всего, - http://dev.odnoklassniki.ru/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=12878032

Answer (score 1):

Вероятно как то так

```
    <?// this.php

$client_secret = 'секретный ключ приложения';
$clientId   ='идентификатор приложения';
$scope ='перечень прав доступа';

function send_post($post_url,$post_data)
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $post_url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "coocie.dat");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "coocie.dat");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:9.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/9.0.1");
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
};

if (empty($_GET['code'])) 
{
    header('location http://www.odnoklassniki.ru/oauth/authorize?client_id=$clientId&scope=$scope&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http://site/this.php');
}else{
    $url='http://api.odnoklassniki.ru/oauth/token.do';
    $data = array(
        'code '=>$_GET['code'],
        'redirect_uri'=>'http://site/this.php',
        'grant_type'=>'authorization_code',
        'client_id'=>$clientId,
        'client_secret'=>$client_secret
    )
    $data=json_decode(send_post($url,$data));
    $token = $data->access_token;
}
```

Подробнее про параметры смотрите по ссылке выше.
Запросы к api делать передавая в параметрах полученный access_token

Comment: неделя некропостинга на хэшкоде ?

Comment: @eicto сейчас увидел даты, и не понял как нашел этот пост...

Comment: Через текущие вопросы :) . Просто тема популярная и я решил, что негоже старой ссылке лежать.

По делу: подскажите, чем по сути отличается Ваш ответ от того, который был?

Comment: @Михаил М в предыдущем требуется логин и пароль, а у меня по API)